# Why Isn't There a Jedi Breeding Program?

Tags: star-wars

I know that the Jedi are not supposed to have attachments with others (so it doesn't interfere with their work) and that would effect romantic relationships.  However Force sensitivity is, at least sometimes, able to be passed on genetically.

Why hasn't there been some kind of breeding program to encourage more people with a higher level of Force sensitivity from the offspring such a program would create?

Comment: This sounds like something more along the lines of what the Dark Side would be interested in.  So, the right question might be "Why isn't there a Sith breeding program?".  Then again, that would violate the Rule of Two, which has been pretty well covered in other questions here, I think.

Comment: A "Jedi breeding programme" ... seriously?

Comment: What do you mean there's no Jedi Breeding Program? What do you call LucasFilm then?

Comment: I think, Lia was introduced for the same purpose..

Comment: @Wikis: Actually, thinking about one question was what led to conversations that led to the others.

Comment: Why is everyone (like @bitmask) so shocked?  How else would they produce a Kwisatz Haderach?  Seriously, there's one in _Dune_ and nobody's shocked or offended by that one.

Comment: @Tango: The Bene Gesserit kind of prove the point. They're pretty close to the Dark Side themselves, at least in the first three books. The point of their breeding program is to ensure their own political dominion over the human race, after all. They mature somewhat in the latter novels.

Comment: @Tango: Take "everyone (like @bitmask)" and turn it into "just @bitmask".

Comment: For the protocol, I wasn't shocked or offended, I just thought it was a whimsical question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not only was there no Jedi "breeding program," Jedi were forbidden from reproducing at all (except [cereans](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Cerean) due to their low birth rates). In one of the EU books, [Vergere](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Vergere) told Luke it was to prevent a "dynasty," like the (then) "three generations of Skywalkers, all strong in the Force."  [I believe that's the actual quote, unfortunately I don't have the book to check.]

I'm sure you can imagine that if there were a particularly powerful family, they could come to dominate and corrupt the Jedi Order.

Comment: The Skywalker family certainly doesn't have a great track record; of five Force-sensitive direct descendants of Shmi Skywalker, two fall to the Sith in a very dramatic way (Anakin Skywalker/Darth Vader and Jacen Solo/Darth Caedus).

Comment: @KeithS - should be six force-sensitive descendants (Anakin, Luke, Leia, Jacen, Jaina, Anakin)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any kind of breeding program for humans in real life. The only breeding programs I am familiar with are for dogs maybe.

It just doesn't seem natural.

Jedi in general are unattached to things. Why would they want to game the whole life and force thing? It doesn't seem to make sense in their universe for people, nor ours.

Comment: Have you really never heard of eugenics? You'd be surprised how many people actually think selectively breeding humans is a good thing. (I'm not one of them by a long shot.). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eugenics

Comment: And, for a less blatant example, look at how many sperm and egg banks pay more for sperm and eggs from intelligent, healthy, white people and similarly charge more.